# addclass, removeclass not working when page loads initially on changepage

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, addclass

I have an app with 3 pages. Let's call them `A`, `B` and `C`.

I make an Ajax call to build the pages and change an icon depending on a flag (let's say `flag1`) and change page depending on `flag2`. Icon appears on all 3 pages with different IDs `sel1`, `sel2` and `sel3`.

It works fine most of the time except when I change page the first time in a session to either page A, B or C. In this case, the icons don't switch. Any help appreciated.

Here are the code snippets

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#sendajax").click(function() {               
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "servlet2",  datatype: "json", 
         success:  populatedata});              
        };
});

    Function populatedata(data){        
       if (data.flag1 == "A" ){
          buildpageA(data);
          $.mobile.changePage("#pageA", {transition:"fade"});   
          $("#pageA").trigger('refresh');                   
    } else if  (data.flag1 == "B" ){
          buildpageB(data);
          $.mobile.changePage("#pageB", {transition:"fade"});   
         $("#pageB").trigger('refresh');
    }else  if(data.flag1 == "C" ){
         buildpageC(data);
         $.mobile.changePage("#pageC", {transition:"fade"});    
         $("#pageC").trigger('refresh');
    }

    Function buildpageA(data){
      if  (data.flag2 != "")                     
    $('#sel1').attr('data-icon', 'info').find('.ui-icon').
              removeClass('ui-icon-info').addClass('ui-icon-error');                
      else
     $('#sel1').attr('data-icon', 'error').find('.ui-icon').
                addClass('ui-icon-info').removeClass('ui-icon-error');              
          $("#sel1").trigger('refresh');
          ……
            }
         }

      Function buildpageB(data){
           if  (data.flag2 != "")                    
        $('#sel2').attr('data-icon', 'info').find('.ui-icon').
                removeClass('ui-icon-info').addClass('ui-icon-error');      
           else
        $('#sel2').attr('data-icon', 'error').find('.ui-icon').
                addClass('ui-icon-info').removeClass('ui-icon-error');          
           $("#sel2").trigger('refresh');
         ……
         }

          Function buildpageC(data){
             ...... you get the point    .}
```

JSP:

```
     <body>
      <page data-role= page  id =”pageA”> 
        <a href="#" data-role="button"   id="sel1" data-icon="" ></a></page>

      <page data-role= page  id =”pageB”>
        <a href="#" data-role="button"   id="sel2" data-icon="" ></a> </page>

      <page data-role= page  id =”pageC”>
        <a href="#" data-role="button"   id="sel3" data-icon="" ></a></page>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change icon, use `.buttonMarkup`.

```
$('#sel').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'error' });
```

> Note: For jQuery Mobile, don't use `.ready()`, stick to jQuery Mobile events. http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/